# Equivalence of spans given a vector is constructed using all linearly independent vectors in two sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $$S_{1}=\left\{ a_{0},a_{1},\dots,a_{k}\right\} , S_{2}=\left\{ b_{0},b_{1},\dots,b_{k}\right\} $$ be two sets containing linearly independent vectors $a_j, b_j$ for $j=1,\dots,k$. To be clear, $a_j$ is linearly independent with any other vector in $S_1$, and $b_j$ is linearly independent with any other vector in $S_2$. No relation is given between the vectors in $S_1$ and $S_2$ except that there exists a vector such that $$v=\sum_{j=0}^{k}c_{j}a_{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}p_{j}b_{j},\quad c_{j}\neq0,p_{j}\neq0,\;\forall j=\left\{ 0,1,\dots,k\right\}.$$ Can we prove or disprove the following statement? $$ {\rm{span}}(a_{0},a_{1},\dots,a_{k})={\rm{span}}(b_{0},b_{1},\dots,b_{k})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spans need not be equal.

For example, take $$S_1 = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ and $$S_2 = \left\{  \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$

Then $S_1$ and $S_2$ are linearly independent, $$ \mathbf{v}:= \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} =    \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}- \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} $$ is in both spans and the coefficients are all non-zero, but the spans are unequal since $  \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is not in $ \operatorname{span}(S_1)$  but is in $ \operatorname{span}(S_2)$ .

Comment: I am sorry, I was writing my answer and only when I submitted it I notice your similar answer. I delete mine 

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not necessarily true. Hint: Think of the $xy$ plane and the $yz$ plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.